# I want a solution to change my state just after I get a future data without any tap action in Flutter

Tags: flutter, setstate, flutter-futurebuilder

I get the error but still I want a solution to change my state just after I get a future data without any tap action.

```
FutureBuilder(
                      future: blogServices.articleComment(token, widget.article.id),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        // print(token);
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Container();
                        } else if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.done &&
                            snapshot.data != null) {
                          List<ArticleComment> comments = snapshot.data;
                          setState(() {. <-------- Error!!!!!!!! 
                            commentsCount=comments.length;
                          });
                          return Container();
                        } else {
                          return CircularProgressIndicator();
                        }
                      },
                    ),
```

Comment: i have also used  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setState(() {
        commentsCount = count;
      });
    }); the state changed but the future builder is looping infinitely.

Comment: kindly state your problem clear more. Elaborate the code and also add more code snippet because of the code.

Comment: without out callback function, you don't allow to call the `setState()`, if you want to use `commentsCount` outside future builder you need to call your API from `initState`

Comment: but it will re-call the future of futurebuilder

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, So instead of

```
setState(() {. <-------- Error!!!!!!!! 
   commentsCount=comments.length;
});
```

I used the code below

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) { setState(() { commentsCount = count; }); });
```

and the loading part was because of my condition snapshot.connectionState ==
ConnectionState.done so I removed that and just gave snapshot.data != null. It worked for me!!